# How to close printing window

Tags: javascript, printing, window

I want to close the window which has printing dialog on that using window.close() function.
I realize that, if the window does not have printing dialog, the window.close() function will works fine.
Here is the example code:

```
<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close "myWindow"</button>
<script>
var myWindow;
function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
}
function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();
}
</script>
```

But if I put the print() function into the above code, I will not be albe to click the close window button until the printing dialog is closed.
Here is the example code

```
<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close "myWindow"</button>
<script>
var myWindow;
function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
    myWindow.print();
}
myWindow.print() {
    myWindow.close();
}
```

I want to know why does that happen and how can I close the window which contains printing dialog.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `mywindow.print() myWindow.close();` separately to the function, put myWindow.close() inside the function then just call that. It seems weird that you're doing myWindow.print() and closing inside of that, I dont think that'd work.

Comment: I want to close the window by clicking the Close "myWindow" button.